# FullScreen video Player in react JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am using react js NOT react native, I want to make a video player which gets full screen on some action like click of button.

On large screen it worked fine with js FullScreenApi, on mobile we need to change the orientation with full screen, just like youtube we click button it changes to fullscreen and landscape orientation.
How can we achieve this mission?

```
const videoPlayerFullScreen = (e) => {
    let orientation = screen.orientation
    if (screenWidth < 768) {
      // alert("clicked")
      console.log(orientation)
      orientation.unlock()
      // screen.orientation.angle = 90
      // screen.orientation.angle(90)
      screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary")
      // document.getElementById("live_videoPlayer").requestFullscreen()
      console.log(orientation)
    } else {
      document.getElementById("live_videoPlayer").requestFullscreen()  
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with `screen.orientation.lock`?

Comment: I don't know but it is not working .